# Chocolate hazelnut: efficacy of mixing crushed&roasted hazelnuts to sauce

Tags: chocolate, roasting, nuts

I would like to know of roasting and crushing hazelnuts, then mixing them with chocolate sauce, is enough to create a nice choco-hazelnut syrup?

(I recently asked if blending roasted hazelnuts will yield oil, but I was told I needed an oilpress.)

End product is mixing the sauce as a sort of "nutella" latte. (I run a cafe).

Thanks!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gianduja_%28chocolate%29. Basically, if you don't have previous experience in an area of cooking and baking, you can save yourself much time and expensive materials by first working off existing recipes and getting a feel for what happens before starting to craft own recipes.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to really know for sure is to give it a try, but I suspect that for a liquid application it will be difficult to get the sauce both thin enough to dissolve easily, and smooth enough to avoid a grainy or chunky texture.

You'll have to blend the hazelnuts very well at minimum - I'd pulverize them first in a blender or food processor, add the chocolate sauce, and then blend for several minutes' more time.  You may have to thin the result with a little water (warmed so as not to seize the mixture).  A run through a sieve or cheesecloth to strain out remaining pieces would be a good idea.

With all that blending and filtering, your yields will probably be pretty low.  One alternative you could try would be a [hazelnut flavoring](https://www.beanilla.com/hazelnut-flavor) of some kind.  A natural extract should lend a distinct hazelnut flavor to any other sauce or mixture (I'd avoid cheaper extracts labelled "artificial" though).  From a practical perspective it will be easier to mix without texture issues, and if purchased in quantity probably won't be much more expensive than preparing hazelnuts from scratch.

Comment: I do plan to just leave the bits inside the jar. They can fall into the end product, but it won't be much harm! Thank you for your answer.